# (Windows 8.1) Launch a specific software if IP address is 192.168.49.*

Tags: networking, script, vbscript, lync, lync-2013

I know there's is a way to launch an executable when specific condition are met, but i'm not familiar with programming.

Is there a way to launch a software, in my case Skype For Business if my local ip is within a subnet (e.g. 192.168.49.*). I only want to make this works only if my Local Area Network card is connected to that subnet.

Correct me if i'm wrong but, I think the best way to do so would be to trigger a vbs file like 30 seconds after the logon using windows task manager.

I'm not able to craft that kind of script and my google searches haven't been successful !

***Thanks guys !***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I run a program if my local ip is within a subnet?

> For example `192.168.49.*`

The following batch file will run `notepad` if your local IP address is in the range `192.168.49.*`:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem get ip address
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 %computername% -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do set _ip=%%a
rem get subnet
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%b in ("%_ip%") do set _subnet=%%b.%%c.%%d
rem check for matching subnet
if [%_subnet%] equ [192.168.49] notepad
```

Notes:

- replace `notepad` with the name of the program you want to run.
- place a copy of the batch file in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` to run on login.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.